# What's a "rank-two update" to a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I'm reading a book, and on its numerical optimization chapter, more precisely in the BFGS algorithm section, the authors state that it's a "rank-two update to the matrix". I've searched for the definition, but I only found the definition for the rank-one update [here](https://statlect.com/matrix-algebra/matrix-inversion-lemmas).

So my question is what is a rank-2 update, and why is the BFGS an example of such an update.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A rank-two update means we are adding a matrix whose rank is two, e.g. $A+B$ where $B$ is of rank two.  The usefulness of this in connection with BFGS is that to retain symmetry, [rank one updates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_rank-one) would necessarily take the special form $xx^T$.  This turns out not to be very helpful in approximating the Hessian, while rank two updates can be chosen more flexibly  from the form $xy^T + yx^T$.  Is that enough information?  I could post a more detailed response as an Answer.

Comment: @hardmath thanks for the comment. Well, I think I understand, but if you have time, I would be interested in an answer with a bit more detail, so that I can be sure I got. ;)

Comment: a rank-two update is the same as two rank-one updates, so $A+xx^T+yy^T$ is a rank-two update to $A$

Answer (score 3):

It is two independent rank-one updates performed simultaneously, or if you want, the addition of a rank-2 matrix. This happens because you are updating a symmetric matrix in a symmetric way with the dyadic product $ab^T$ and its transpose $ba^T$, which can also be expressed as some difference of the symmetric updates $(a+b)(a+b)^T$ and $(a-b)(a-b)^T$.

---

For the secant condition one wants to enforce $B_+s=y$. With a rank-1 update that would give $(B+ab^T)s=y$ giving $a=y-Bs$ and with some other geometric constraints $b=\alpha s$. This is not very symmetric in most cases.

So one tries $B_+=B+ab^T+ba^T$ with $y=B_+s=Bs+a(b^Ts)+b(a^Ts)$. Then again for some kind of geometric minimality one gets that $a$ and $b$ have to be linear combinations of $y$ and $Bs$ which again should be sufficient to determine them.

Comment: Hi Lutz, thanks for your answer. I still have a doubt. Let's use the notation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm

So, B_t is being updated with rank-2 transformation because we have $y_k y_k^T$ and $B_{t-1}s_{k-1} (B_{t-1}s_{k-1})^T$ ?